# Why does my mob farm not work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I built mob farm, I've been building it since like 2 years ago and it always works, except now it wont, I read that if I light the caves under the farm more mobs would spawn in it, but I than found a zombie spawner right under the farm, think it has anything to do with why nothing is spawning in it?

Comment: What version/snapshot are you in?

Comment: Mob dynamics change with every release, and many farm designs break over time.  A screenshot (or multiple screen shots) of your mob farm design would help tremendously.